# Fixed the position of the item color as the item sliding and sliding?

Tags: android

The effect of like TimerPicker display box!

[image: screenshot]

For example, such a fixed way!!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take some time to check out [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: What's the question exactly? What's your code currently?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

call this method.

```
showDialog(0);
```

and add this custom dialog.

```
   int year_x,month_x,day_x;
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if(id==0)
        return  new DatePickerDialog(this,datepicker,year_x,month_x,day_x);
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datepicker=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year_x=year;
        month_x=monthOfYear+1;
        day_x=dayOfMonth;
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.editdate)).setText(day_x+"/"+month_x+"/"+year_x);
        DataBase.setUserDateofbirth(day_x+"/"+month_x+"/"+year_x,Profile.this);
    }
};
```

I hope its solve your problem.

Comment: Now you can't fixed,I use the TextView and RecyclerView do this function！